# Icons disappearing in More tab

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

In my iPad application, I use a tabBarController. I run the following code to select to a specific tab :

```
[tabBarController setSelectedViewController:myNavigationController];
```

(I modify the property `selectedViewController` of the class `UITabBarController`, see [apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html))

This works perfectly ; the only issue is that when the users navigate back to the "More..." screen with the upper left button, the icon for the previously selected tab is missing :

[image: an icon is missing]

When I navigate manually, there is no problem. The icons are always visible in "More" screen. The issue occurs only when I use the method `setSelectedViewController`.

The tab bar items are created as follows :

```
newVC = [[SynchronizeViewController alloc] init];
newVC.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] 
    initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"SYNCHRONIZE", @"synchronize tab label") 
    image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"02-redo.png"] tag:0];
```

Has someone encountered the same issue and found a way to fix this ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: please post your setSelectedViewController method.

Comment: @Sunny That's the setter corresponding to the property `selectedViewController` of `UITabBarController`. See [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: post the image file, please.

Comment: @Holex My image is just a standard PNG file, why ?

Comment: So the icon was there _before_ selecting another controller? It dissapears _after_ the selection? Does this happen with all icons (all controllers)?

Comment: have you set image as same as other view controllers, cross check the image name Mr. Super Chafouin

Comment: @iMartin Yes this issue occurs with all controllers. I can see that the icon has disappeared hen I click back on the "More..." tab. Before the icon is here. When I navigate manually with the user interface, there is no problem. The issue occurs only when I use `setSelectedViewController`

Comment: @Vinodh The image name is correct, I can see it when I navigate manually. The image disappears only when I use the method `setSelectedViewController`.

Comment: @SuperChafouin, because definitely something is wrong with the icon (e.g. format, colour or alpha channel), if it does not show properly.

Comment: @holex But the image ***is* showing property**. Please, read before you write. The image _dissapears after specific action_.

Comment: Posted answer below, but now I have one question: _Why do you use `-tag:` method there? And what does it do? And why the tag is `0`?_

Comment: @iMartin Because the constructor includes this `tag` parameter. I always set it to zero.

Comment: @SuperChafouin Oh sorrry, didn't notice that it's part of constructor ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Could you please add next method to Synchronize controller:**

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    UITableView *view = (UITableView *)appDelegate.tabBarController.moreNavigationController.topViewController.view;
    [view reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Yes, that works ! We need to refresh the `moreNavigationController` table view and the icon is displayed. Seems to be a bug in iOS ?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that **you are creating** `UITabBarItem` yourself. From the docs of `-tabBarItem`:

> The first time the property is accessed, the `UITabBarItem` is created.

So you don't need to create it, just do this:

```
newVC.tabBarItem.title = @"Your Title"; // Default is view controller's title.
newVC.tabBarItem.image = yourImage;
```

---

*Attempt for explanation:* For some reason the `UITabBarController` decided to internally re-create all tab bar items, or what. And your instance was lost and default title was used. Or maybe only image was lost, who knows. This is called *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this good idea, but I tried it, and the icon is still lost.

Comment: But, please, follow this answer to prevent other unexpected bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the file from the project. Get a clean build and add it back to the project with a different name.